# How to run my code on the specific thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

How to run my code on the specific thread?

If "the specific thread" is main ui Thread, I can do use runOnUiThread method.

But "the specific thread" is not ui Thread and "the specific thread" is not made by me.

"the specific thread" is made by some library.

But I can access "the specific thread".

Like this, `Thread theSpecificThread = getThread();`

How to run my code on the specific thread like runOnUiThread(new Runnable())?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to do this? You usually can't just run code on an already executing thread unless that thread provides a method for doing so (the way the UI thread does.)

Comment: @dlev I use libgdx. I want to access glthread for asynchronous url image rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You have to arrange for the thread to call it.  If this thread is buried in an opaque library, doesn't call any accessible methods or events and provides no way of signaling it to do something you can get at, then I'm afraid that you have a big problem.

Comment: I use libgdx. I want to access glthread for asynchronous url image rendering.